# How to find div inside another div using HtmlUnit?

Tags: html, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am working on some project where in i need scrap some information from different website.I am using `HtmlUnit` for this purpose,But problem is i am unable to traverse through the elements on one page.

Example:

```
  <div id="some_id">

      <div>

        <div>

           <div>

              ......
                       many divs in between
              ......

               <div id="my_target_div"> some information </div>

                ........

                ........

                 </div>
```

Now how get `div` with id `my_target_div`  and information inside that `div`

Comment: what have you already tried?

Answer (score 5):

Use **getHtmlElementById**.

Check **[documentation](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getHtmlElementById%28java.lang.String%29)**.

An example:

```
@Test
public void getElements() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");
    final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("my_target_div");

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

**[Source.](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, i have already solved it myself. Anyway i am up voting you for spending your quality time in answering this question, which may help others who have similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page;
  HtmlElement div= (HtmlElement) page2.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='my_target_div']");
```

This will solve your problem.